# Add a vertical line in a react-vis chart where mousepointer is hovered

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-vis

I'm evaluating react-vis. Let's say I have a 
[react-vis simple chart](https://codepen.io/jckr/pen/oWLbYQ), how would you add a vertical line that moves with the mouse when the chart is hovered?
My guess is that I need to add a crosshair component inside the XYPlot, and maybe a YAxis component. But I don't understand how, and I cant't find any releant examples.

```
function Chart({data}) {
  return <XYPlot width={400} height={300}><XAxis/><YAxis/>
    <HorizontalGridLines />
    <VerticalGridLines />
    <LineMarkSeries data={data} />
    </XYPlot>;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to add a vertical line with a `<Crosshair />` component. You can use this example in the documentation located [here](https://github.com/uber/react-vis/blob/master/showcase/axes/dynamic-crosshair.js). You need to set `onMouseLeave` and `onNearestX` handlers to update the `Crosshairs` line's value. The trick is that you have to put `divs` inside the `Crosshair` component so it won't render the value box. I'm using React Hooks to answer your question, but you could have used state with a class ([React Hooks State Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html)).

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function Chart({data}) {
  const [points, setPoints] = useState([]);

  return <XYPlot
    width={400}
    height={300}
    onMouseLeave={() => setPoints([])}
    >
    <XAxis/>
    <YAxis/>
    <HorizontalGridLines />
    <VerticalGridLines />
    <LineMarkSeries
      data={data}
      onNearestX={v => setPoint([v])}
    />
    <Crosshair values={point}>
      {/* Divs inside Crosshair Component required to prevent value box render */}
      <div></div>
    </Crosshair>
  </XYPlot>;
}
```